# Hololens 2 Multi-User Capabilities error DllNotFoundException: AzureSpatialAnchors

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, multi-user, azure-spatial-anchors

I've been following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-02 to make a Hololens 2 app that can be used by 2 or more users, however, I haven't been able to make it work, because after finishing the tutorial and trying to run the app, I get this build error message:

DllNotFoundException: AzureSpatialAnchors

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, I tried googling this problem but I seem to get nowhere. pls keep in mind that i'm a new developer unu
I included an image to give a better idea of the problem, it seems to be the only error message D:

(I tought the problem may have been something to do with my spatial anchor resource on azure, but even after creating a new resource and pasting the new ids, it seems to still have the problem unu. also, i do have a hololens 2 visor, so i'm sure the problem doesn't have to do with the emulator while pressing play.)

[i hope the image helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnqHR.jpg)

Comment: Can you follow this tutorial and complete it? It will probably fix the missing dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-hololens?tabs=azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

Azure Spatial Anchors are not supported in Unity Player (per your image, you are running it in Player) nor Hololens Emulator. You need to build & deploy the app to a Hololens in order to test ASA.